# Remove non-compliant bundle from store

Tags: android, google-play-console

One app bundle was live for sometime in Play Store. It became Google policy non-compliant and Google removed the app from play store. Now I have resolved the compliance issue and sent the updated file for review. Google is rejecting it saying that earlier file is active.

In the mail I received, it's mentioned that I need to go to explore app bundle and go the the specific release which has the issue and click on manage track. However I see only view track and I am not able to edit anything there.

How can I resolve this?

This is what is see and the version code 6 needs to be deleted, version code 9 is the updated one:

[image]

The menu item when clicked i dont see an option to delete.. below is what i see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess loaded image in your question is under release history section. You can click the arrow which version you want to delete like below.

[image]

Then next page, under app bundle section there is three dots vertically. There is could be option to delete.

[image]

**UPDATE**
This could solve this problem:

1.Create new release
[image]

2.There is section named "not included". In there you should select "include" option for the version you desire to remove.
[image]

3.Then same page again, "included" section you should click three dots vertically set for options and select "Remove app bundle".
[image]

4.You must upload new version of your app with this settings. This way old version of your app will be removed from Google Play.

Comment: no. i dont see an option to delete it.. i have updated my question with the screenshot

Comment: Could you try this: Create new release and upload new version of app. Then on same page in not included section click include button. Then in included section open three dots which set vertically again there should be remove option.

Comment: I updated my answer according to my comment.